# React HOC functional component: How to make any children have Parent's state and logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components, react-children

I am trying to create a React function Hover component ([link to a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-danilo-hrgpl?file=/src/App.js))  which will give any of its `{children}` hover behaviors i.e. its internal hooks and methods:

```
function WithHover({ children }) {
  const [hover, setIsHover] = React.useState(null);
  const [hoverText, setHoverText] = React.useState("");
  const mouseOver = () => setIsHover((hover) => true);
  const mouseOut = () => setIsHover((hover) => false);

  const childrenWithExtraProp = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      hover,
      setIsHover,
      hoverText,
      setHoverText
    });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "20%",
          height: "20",
          display: "block",
          marginBottom: "5%",
          backGroundColor: "pink"
        }}
      >
        <p>{hoverText}</p>
      </div>

      <main onMouseOver={mouseOver} onMouseOut={mouseOut}>
        {childrenWithExtraProp}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {

  function Button({ children }) {
    return <button>{children}</button>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <WithHover />
      <Button hover={true}>foo</Button>
      <WithHover />
    </div>
  );
}
```

However when I checkin the `<Button/>` to see if the props were there via a console, I got a empty array?

function Button(props) {
console.log('props', props); // zero props
return {props.children};
}

What am I missing?

Comment: It is better to use the context API for something like this

Comment: or a custom hook if each component needs its own instance of hover state/functions

Comment: @RameshReddy Yeah, I was just curious for a few components here and there. Thanks though!

Comment: Btw, its not HOC. Which is btw good, you shouldn't combine such pattern with function components.

Answer (score 0):

You not actually using the `children` prop (it always nullish) since you closing the tag `<WithHover/>`.

Instead, try:

```
<WithHover>
  <Button>foo</Button>
</WithHover>
```

[image: Edit romantic-allen-fl31f]

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the `WithHover` tag the wrong way and see the error is displayed on the screen as well. It is clearly showing you the way to resolve this issue by pointing out the error due to which it is failing. As Dennis Vash has mentioned in his answer the tag should be closed like:

```
<WithHover>
  <Button>foo</Button>
</WithHover>
```